# Wifi direction/location finding

Tags: wireless-networking

Is it possible, by measuring the signal strength at different locations, or other means, to ascertain the approximate location of a wifi signal?

What software would you recommend to do this? (For me, OSX, but feel free to list others)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For OS X there's [Kismac](http://trac.kismac-ng.org/).

Another one for Windows that looks cool (I've not had a chance to try this one yet) is [Ekahau HeatMapper](http://www.ekahau.com/products/heatmapper/overview.html).

Answer (score 1):

See [Vistumbler Detects Wi-Fi Hotspots, Maps Them](http://lifehacker.com/5071140/vistumbler-detects-wi+fi-hotspots-maps-them) :

> Windows Vista only: Free, open-source
>   application Vistumbler scans wireless
>   networks within range of your Wi-Fi
>   antenna, tracks signal strength over
>   time, and handles pretty much
>   everything else that other apps of
>   this kind do. **What sets Vistumbler
>   apart from the rest is its support for
>   GPS and live Google Earth tracking,
>   which plots hotspots on a map**.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[This app](https://itunes.apple.com/ca/app/netspot-wifi-survey-wireless/id514951692?mt=12) is currently free on the App Store.  It seems to be more suited to mapping signals within a building rather than war-driving, but in case that's what you're looking for, check it out.

Answer (score 0):

I always liked [netstumbler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NetStumbler).

You can read about war driving [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wardriving) and probably get some ideas of programs that would help you.